# SI <int-xml:xpath-filter /> behavior

Tags: xpath, spring-integration

I have a scenario where I am filtering a xml payload based on a xpath value.

```
<int:channel id="documentReceiptFilterChannel" />
<int:chain input-channel="documentReceiptFilterChannel" output-channel="nullChannel">
    <!-- Filter to discard message if <statusCode> value is 'EMLOK' -->
    <int-xml:xpath-filter match-type="regex" match-value="^(?!\bEMLOK\b).*$" discard-channel="nullChannel">
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//*[local-name()='statusCode']" />
    </int-xml:xpath-filter>
    <int:service-activator expression="@opsLogger.logError('TransactionId=' + headers.correlationId, ' Msg=' + @opsExceptionUtils.createOPSExceptionInstance(#root))" />
</int:chain>
```

Following is the payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetDocumentReceiptReply xmlns="http://example.org"
                                xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <mergeReceiptDeliveryStatus>
      <statusCode>EMLOK</statusCode>
   </mergeReceiptDeliveryStatus>
</GetDocumentReceiptReply>
```

My requirement is that when `<statusCode>EMLOK</statusCode>` element is available, discard the message and hence `nullChannel` is mentioned as `discard-channel`.
But then there is any other value, proceed to the next step in the chain and do the error logging - `<int:service-activator expression="@opsLogger.logError()`.

The above setup works fine as long as `<statusCode>` element is present in the payload. But doesn't work on the following situations:

1. `<statusCode></statusCode>`
2. `<statusCode/>`
3. `<statusCode>` is missing
4. Or any other xml payload

To get rid of namespace issues, the xpath expression is formed as `<int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//*[local-name()='statusCode']" />`. The xpath value is matched against regex expression `match-type="regex" match-value="^(?!\bEMLOK\b).*$"` (For value != '`EMLOK`').

What happens when `<int-xml:xpath-expression />` evaluation fails?

My only requirement is that if `<statusCode>EMLOK</statusCode>` is present, discard the message, else for all other, log an error in the log file. (And not to throw an exception that will propagate to error-channel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom subclass of `AbstractXPathMessageSelector` and delegate to a `BooleanTestXPathMessageSelector` and a `RegexTestXPathMessageSelector`, or simply use 2 filters...

```
<int:chain input-channel="documentReceiptFilterChannel" output-channel="errors">
    <int-xml:xpath-filter discard-channel="errors">
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//*[local-name()='statusCode']" />
    </int-xml:xpath-filter>
    <int-xml:xpath-filter match-type="regex" match-value="^(?!\bEMLOK\b).*$">
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//*[local-name()='statusCode']" />
    </int-xml:xpath-filter>
</int:chain>

<int:service-activator 
    expression="@opsLogger.logError('TransactionId=' + headers.correlationId, ' Msg=' + @opsExceptionUtils.createOPSExceptionInstance(#root))" />
```

Notice that you don't need to discard to `nullChannel` - just omitting the discard channel will cause discards. Messages that pass the second filter go to the chain's output channel.

The custom selector would be a little more efficient because only one conversion to node is needed.